# Deepin Linux can't share folders

Tags: shared-folders, lan, deepin

I have a deepin linux (debian based) installed on my notebook and I'm trying to share folders from this computer with a W10 computer so I tried to share the folder and on windows type the user and password from deepin (screenshot):
[image]

(acesso negado = denied access)

But I have no results, the **funny (weird)** thing is that if I share some subfolder from user directory like uaimax/documents it works like a charm but I'm not being able to make it work when I share some folder from my NTFS partition (secondary hard drive)

There's something I can do about it or I'll be able to share only subdirs from user folder?

Comment: What are the permission's on said folder?

Comment: uaimax@uaimax-PC:~$ sudo ls -la /media/uaimax/BUNKER/DOWNLOADS\ TV/VIDEOSTV/
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 uaimax uaimax    0 out 23 18:51 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 uaimax uaimax 4096 nov 30 17:30 ..